# Rotating seconds for each second in Stopwatch in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am ending my Stopwatch project in React, and have problems with rotation of seconds for each second defined in countTimers method. I defined the state of rotation with 0(deg). Then in countTimers function in setInterval changed rotation state to 360(deg), and after that with condition: 
 `if(this.state.seconds > 0 || this.state.seconds < 60 && this.state.rotation === 360)` tried to execute the transition for each second, and after each transition to set the rotation state to 0(deg).

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Timer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            count: 0,
            pause: true,
            rotation: 0
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.countTimers();
    }

    countTimers = () => {
        let counter = setInterval(() => {
            if (!this.state.pause) { 
                    this.setState({
                        count: this.state.count + 1,
                        rotation: 360
                    });

                    if(this.state.seconds > 0 || this.state.seconds < 60 && this.state.rotation === 360) {
                        document.querySelector('.seconds').style.transition = "all 0.1s ease";
                        document.querySelector('.seconds').style.transform= "rotateX(360deg)";
                    }

                    this.setState({
                        rotation: 0
                    });
            }
        }
        , 1000);
    }

    startHandler = () => {
        this.setState({
            pause: false
        })
    }

    pauseHandler = () => {
        this.setState({
            pause: true
        })
    }
```

The transition is being accomplished only one time, after componentDidMount and by clicking on start button.

```
    render () {
        let days = Math.floor(this.state.count / (1 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        let hours = Math.floor((this.state.count % (1 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1 * 60 * 60));
        let minutes = Math.floor((this.state.count % (1 * 60 * 60)) / (1 * 60));
        let seconds = Math.floor((this.state.count % (1 * 60)) / 1);

        return (
            <div className="Timer">
                <h1>{'STOPWATCH'}</h1>
                <div className="stopwatch-wrapper">
                    <span className="days">{days}:</span>
                    <span className="hours">{hours}:</span>
                    <span className="minutes">{minutes}:</span>
                    <span className={"seconds"}>{seconds}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="buttons-wrapper">
                    <button id="start" onClick={this.startHandler}>START</button>
                    <button id="pause" onClick={this.pauseHandler}>PAUSE</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Timer;
```

Has anyone idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got many problems, first off `seconds` doesn't exist in state, so your condition for changing the rotation never returns true. Next, you need to set the spans display css property to `inline-block`. Lastly, we're using React! No need to manipulate the elements style directly, doing it in the render function works just fine and is much more Reacty.

Run the snippet below to see it working

```js
class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      count: 0,
      pause: true,
      rotation: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.countTimers();
  }

  countTimers = () => {
    let counter = setInterval(() => {
      if (!this.state.pause) {
        this.setState({
          count: this.state.count + 1,
          rotation: this.state.rotation === 359.9 ? 0 : 359.9,
        });
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  startHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      pause: false
    })
  }

  pauseHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      pause: true
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {rotation, count} = this.state;
    let days = Math.floor(count / (1 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    let hours = Math.floor((count % (1 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1 * 60 * 60));
    let minutes = Math.floor((count % (1 * 60 * 60)) / (1 * 60));
    let seconds = Math.floor((count % (1 * 60)) / 1); 

    return (
      <div className="Timer">
          <h1>{'STOPWATCH'}</h1>
          <div className="stopwatch-wrapper">
              <span className="days">{days}:</span>
              <span className="hours">{hours}:</span>
              <span className="minutes">{minutes}:</span>
              <span className="seconds" style={{transform: `rotate(${rotation}deg)`}}>{seconds}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="buttons-wrapper">
              <button id="start" onClick={this.startHandler}>START</button>
              <button id="pause" onClick={this.pauseHandler}>PAUSE</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  Timer / > ,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.seconds{
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform 500ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ted, it's working. You are right not to inject pure JS into React code. Span is by default inline element so i didn't add that, of course also not my  timer.css file here, because it would be too long. I always try to escape a lot of state changes when is it possible. My idea is to rotate each second, minute, hours, day when they reach quantitative limit.